# Jest ReferenceError: Cannot access '_default' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs

I have been experiencing a weird error using jest to test my redux-toolkit component. I am using NextJS as my react framework but somehow can not seem to get past the rendering of a component in jest. I have my custom renderer for testing setup like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../../@core/state/store'


const render = (
  ui:any, {
    initialState = {...store.getState()},
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children } : any) => (
    <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  );
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions});
};

export *  from '@testing-library/react';
export { render};
```

and I have my slice setup like this

```
export const AuthSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        started: (state) => {
            state.status = 'pending'
        },
        success: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<User | null>) => {
            state.status = 'successful'
            state.user = payload
        },
        reset: (state) => {
            state.status = 'idle'
        },
        failed: (state, payload: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.message = payload.payload
        }
    },

})

export const { started, success, failed, reset } = AuthSlice.actions

export default AuthSlice.reducer
```

In my Test I have a simple test like this

```
import ForgotPassword from "../../components/Authentication/forgot-password";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "../utils";
describe("Forgot Password Component", () => {
it("it should render the input field", () => {
    
    render(<ForgotPassword />);

  })
});
```

But whenever I run the test I get this error

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access '_default' before initialization

      135 | export const { started, success, failed, reset } = AuthSlice.actions
      136 |
    > 137 | export default AuthSlice.reducer
          | ^
      138 |
```

I have made several research and fixes but could not get it fixed. If I should remove the render from the test everything works fine.

By the way this is my store configuration

```
import { persistStore, persistReducer, FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'my-store',
    storage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I just had the exact same issue. In my case, the imported module had cyclic dependencies. Breaking them solved the issue.